# Removing not matching obj from old array and replace matching obj from new array with old matching obj

Tags: javascript, arrays

I cant figure out how to do this...

```
const arr1 = [{ name: 'peter' }, { name: 'sam', id: 1 }, { name: 'mark' }];
const arr2 = [{ name: 'sam' }, { name: 't' }, { name: 'george' }];
```

Desired outcome:

`const arr2 = [{ name: 'sam', id: 1 }, { name: 't' }, { name: 'george' }];`

Comment: Can you share your code you tried?

Comment: @RomanGavrilov I've tried a lot but removed the code already, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want **the previous item** I would do this:

```js
const arr1 = [{
  name: 'peter'
}, {
  name: 'sam',
  id: 1
}, {
  name: 'mark'
}];
const arr2 = [{
  name: 'sam'
}, {
  name: 't'
}, {
  name: 'george'
}];

const result = arr2.map(item => {
  const previousItem = arr1.find(i => i.name === item.name)
  if (previousItem) {
    return previousItem
  }
  return item
})

console.log(result);
```

However, if you want to combine the old and new data, I would recommend `spread`ing the data together, like so:

```js
const arr1 = [{
  name: 'peter'
}, {
  name: 'sam',
  id: 1
}, {
  name: 'mark'
}];
const arr2 = [{
  name: 'sam'
}, {
  name: 't'
}, {
  name: 'george'
}];

const result = arr2.map(item => {
  const previousItem = arr1.find(i => i.name === item.name)
  if (previousItem) {
    return {
      ...previousItem,
      ...item
    }
  }
  return item
})

console.log(result);
```

Both allude to the same result here, but you would get different results if `arr2`'s "Sam" object had an additional key `"age"` on it...
In this example, the second snippet would keep the `"age"` key because the `spread` (`...`) operation combines the two objects together.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
const arr1 = [{ name: 'peter' }, { name: 'sam', id: 1 }, { name: 'mark' }];
const arr2 = [{ name: 'sam' }, { name: 't' }, { name: 'george' }];

const result = [];
const res1 = arr2.map((item, i) => {
  let index = arr1.findIndex((x) => x.name === item.name);
  if ( index > -1 )
    result.push(arr1[index]);
  else
    result.push(item);
})

console.log(result);
```